# EM Wave shielding of different frequencies

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, radio

Is more aluminium required in Faraday cages to block AM or MW radio waves compared to FM frequencies (of equal power)? If yes, is this difference directly proportional to the decrease in frequency (FM to AM/MW)?

Comment: Not significantly more. You can calculate the required thickness with a skin effect calculator, there are plenty online or write your own spreadsheet. The skin depth is inverse proportional to the square root of the frequency, so if you change the frequency by a factor of 100 (AM in the 1MHz range at the low end to FM at 100MHz), the skin depth will only change by a factor of 10. For 1MHz and aluminum the skin depth is 82um, so a 1mm shield should be plenty. For FM radio a  0.1mm foil will do, but that doesn't have much mechanical stability, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

How thick should the conducting layer be?

The conductive layer can be very thin because of something known as the skin effect. That term describes the tendency of current to flow primarily on the skin of a conductor. As long as the conducting layer is greater than the skin depth, it will provide excellent shielding because the absorption loss will be large. The skin depth is a function of the frequency of the wave and the conductor material. As an example, consider that for a frequency of 200 MHz, the skin depth of aluminum is only about 21 microns. EMP pulses can have frequency content that ranges up to 1,000 MHz. Therefore, wrapping a box in a couple of layers of heavy duty aluminum foil (typically about 24 microns thick) provides the necessary conductor thickness to protect against high-frequency radiated fields. So it isn't a real issue concerning the thickness that much.

Comment: @ CuriousOne & Ed Yablecki:  Thanks both for the above, can the same calculations be applied to radio wave beams ie of a few centimeters in diameter?

Comment: Are you referring to Project Blue Beam?

Comment: Just a general question, to know if there is a difference.